# EF core query group by date and subquery

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "OrderStatusLogs" (
    "Id" UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    "OrderId" UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    "Status" INT NOT NULL,
    "StartDateTime" DATETIMEOFFSET NOT NULL,
    "EndDateTime" DATETIMEOFFSET NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("Id"),
    FOREIGN KEY INDEX "FK_OrderStatusLogs_Orders_OrderId" ("OrderId"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_OrderStatusLogs_Orders_OrderId" FOREIGN KEY ("OrderId") REFERENCES "Orders" ("Id") ON UPDATE NO_ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)
;
```

For the following entity:

```cs
    [DebuggerDisplay(nameof(OrderStatusLog) + " {Status} {StartDateTime} - {EndDateTime}" )]
    public class OrderStatusLog
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public Guid OrderId { get; set; }

        public OrderStatus Status { get; set; }

        public DateTimeOffset StartDateTime { get; set; }

        public DateTimeOffset? EndDateTime { get; set; }
    }

    public enum OrderStatus
    {
        Unknown = 0,
        Pending = 1,
        Processing = 2,
        Shipping = 3,
    }
```

And i'm trying to generate a report which should show how many orders are set to a certain state for a given range.

For example, for the month oktober, we'd have the range 1 to 31 oktober.
The desired output would be something like this:

```
1/10/2021 Pending 21 orders
1/10/2021 Processing 23 orders
1/10/2021 Shipping 33 orders
1/10/2021 Unknown 0 orders
...
31/10/2021 Pending 1 orders
31/10/2021 Processing 3 orders
31/10/2021 Shipping 44 orders
31/10/2021 Unknown 5 orders
```

I'm having some difficulties writing a query in EF that would give me the right output. I can get things to work, but only client-side. I'm trying to make this work in the database instead.

So far i tried:

```cs
            var logsByDayAndOrderId = orderStatusLogs.GroupBy(c => new { c.StartDateTime.Date, c.OrderId }, (key, values) => new
            {
                key.Date,
                key.OrderId,
                MaxStartDateTime = values.Max(x => x.StartDateTime)
            });

            var list = logsByDayAndOrderId.ToList();

            var statusByDayAndOrderId = logsByDayAndOrderId.Select(c => new
            {
                c.Date,
                c.OrderId,
                orderStatusLogs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartDateTime == c.MaxStartDateTime && x.OrderId == c.OrderId).Status
            });

            //var statusByDayAndOrderId = logsByDayAndOrderId.Join(orderStatusLogs.def, inner => new { inner.OrderId, StartDateTime = inner.MaxStartDateTime }, outer => new { outer.OrderId, outer.StartDateTime }, (inner,outer) => new
            //{
            //    inner.Date,
            //    inner.OrderId,
            //    outer.Status
            //}); // TODO rem this query gives more results because of the join. we need an Outer join - but i could not get that to work. the version with select above works better, but then it does not use join so it may be slow(er).

            var list1 = statusByDayAndOrderId.ToList();


            var groupBy = statusByDayAndOrderId
                .GroupBy(c => new { c.Date, c.Status })
                .Select(c => new {  c.Key.Date, c.Key.Status, Count = c.Count() });

            var list2 = groupBy.ToList();
```

Another attempt:

```cs
            var datesAndOrders = orderStatusLogs
                .GroupBy(c => new { c.StartDateTime.Date, c.OrderId }, (key, values) => key);

            var ordersByDateAndActiveStatusLog = orderStatusLogs
                .Select(c => new
                {
                    c.StartDateTime.Date,
                    c.OrderId,
                    ActiveStatusForDate = orderStatusLogs
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.StartDateTime)
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.OrderId == c.OrderId && x.StartDateTime.Date == c.StartDateTime.Date)
                    .Status
                });

            var list = ordersByDateAndActiveStatusLog.ToList();

            var orderCountByDateAndStatus = ordersByDateAndActiveStatusLog
                .GroupBy(c => new { c.Date, c.ActiveStatusForDate }, (key, values) => new
                {
                    key, count = values.Count()
                });

            var list1 = orderCountByDateAndStatus.ToList();
```

Both of these fail because of `Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.`.
This makes sense.

I'm hoping for someone that could help write a Linq query that generates the right data using ef core.

Notes:

- I Solely use the fluent query syntax
- I Have more places where i'd like to get data for each day so any other info or tips and tricks are welcome
- I use net core 5 with ef core 5.0.11 with a MSSQL database

Comment: I can propose solution only with using third party EF Core extension. There is needs to use `VALUES` table to make query work.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv you mean something like a temp table ?

Comment: you need to put your properties in your select query which you gonna use in ```GroupBy``` condition. i think you are missing ```c.Date``` property in the select query

Comment: Well [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) supports local collections in LINQ query, so we can just generate days and prepare needed result.

Comment: If the amount of rows fetched is small, I would fetch the data filtering by StartDateTime and EndDateTime and process them in memory. Otherwise, I would consider creating [an entity mapped to a sql query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#flexible-entity-mapping).

Comment: @MonticolaExplorator this is for a month's range about 20.000 rows. I can actualy retrieve those in memory in about 1.5s so that's not too terrible. If i catch your drift, that would mean there'd be another dbset<OrderStatusByDay> or something that would evaluate to an sql query? hm. I haven't played around with that kind of method.

Comment: @sommmen Yes, the idea would be to create an entity and on model creating configure it as keyless and call `ToTable(null)` so migrations don't create a table for that entity. Create a DBSet on you context and then use it with [a raw query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql), I guess you would have to build your sql query depending on the month you are querying. With this approach, you would have more control of what sql is generated. Anyway, @SvyatoslavDanyliv answer looks promising too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use EF Core extension [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) which has ability to work with local (in-memory) collections in database queries. Disclaimer: i'm one of the creators.

At first define function which generates days sequence:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GenerateDays(int year, int month)
{
  var start = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
  var endDate = start.AddMonths(1);
  while (start < endDate)
  {
    yield return start;
    start = start.AddDays(1);
  }
}
```

Then we can use generated sequence in LINQ Query:

```cs
var days = GenerateDays(2021, 10).ToArray();

using var dc = ctx.CreateLinqToDbConnection();

var totalsQuery =
  from d in days.AsQueryable(dc)
  from l in orderStatusLogs.Where(l =>
      (l.EndDateTime == null || l.EndDateTime >= d) && l.StartDateTime < d.AddDays(1))
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
  group l by new { Date = d, l.Status } into g
  into g
  select new
  {
     g.Key.Date,
     g.Key.Status,
     Count = g.Sum(x => x == null ? 0 : 1),
  };

var result = totalsQuery.ToList();
```

The following SQL should be generated:

```sql
SELECT
    [d].[item],
    [e].[Status],
    Sum(IIF([e].[OrderID] IS NULL, 0, 1))
FROM
(VALUES
    ('2021-05-01T00:00:00'), ('2021-05-02T00:00:00'),
    ('2021-05-03T00:00:00'), ('2021-05-04T00:00:00'),
    ('2021-05-05T00:00:00'), ('2021-05-06T00:00:00'),
    ('2021-05-07T00:00:00'), ('2021-05-08T00:00:00'),
    ('2021-05-09T00:00:00'), ('2021-05-10T00:00:00'),
    ('2021-05-11T00:00:00'), ('2021-05-12T00:00:00'),
    ('2021-05-13T00:00:00'), ('2021-05-14T00:00:00'),
    ('2021-05-15T00:00:00'), ('2021-05-16T00:00:00'),
    ('2021-05-17T00:00:00'), ('2021-05-18T00:00:00'),
    ('2021-05-19T00:00:00'), ('2021-05-20T00:00:00'),
    ('2021-05-21T00:00:00'), ('2021-05-22T00:00:00'),
    ('2021-05-23T00:00:00'), ('2021-05-24T00:00:00'),
    ('2021-05-25T00:00:00'), ('2021-05-26T00:00:00'),
    ('2021-05-27T00:00:00'), ('2021-05-28T00:00:00'),
    ('2021-05-29T00:00:00'), ('2021-05-30T00:00:00'),
    ('2021-05-31T00:00:00')
) [d]([item])
    LEFT JOIN [OrderStatusLogs] [e] ON ([e].[EndDateTime] IS NULL OR [e].[EndDateTime] >= [d].[item]) AND [e].[StartDateTime] < DateAdd(day, 1, [d].[item])
GROUP BY
    [d].[item],
    [e].[Status]
```

Comment: Hiya - thanks for posting an answer. I'll keep this in mind, i'm not sure if the rest of the team would like me to add a library.

Comment: If you are in the process of creating reports, `linq2db` is best way to do that, it covers almost everything from SQL.